# Will you productize stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request

Do you have any plans on productizing this forum for third parties? I'm currently working for a telco provider here in Sweden and we'd like to use your solution on our supportpages, preferably thru an API so we can control the look and feel of the site/pages.

If not, are there any other players out there that offer similar products? We've looked at zendesk, desk.com and a few others but they're all lacking in features such as great tagging, votes on answers, merging of questions and a few other key features for us.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones And the answer to the "productization" more than likely is "been there, done that, not doing it any more".

Comment: Its important to remember that stack exchange is the community as well as the code. You may not get the same results simply using one of the clones

Comment: @Bart - we had recently removed^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hpurged the last remaining SE 1.0 site from our servers, to great rejoicing of the sysadmins.

Comment: We've used AnswerHub but there are many alternatives. Richard is right though - just because you clone it doesn't mean they'll come.

Comment: @Oded I saw some Trello complaints :)

Comment: @Bart - Not who I was thinking about, but yeah, Trello and FogBugs were on SE 1.0 too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you have any plans on productizing this forum for third parties?

We had. It was called Stack Exchange 1.0 and it didn't work for us. So we stopped.

> If not, are there any other players out there that offer similar products?

Sure - there are loads of [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) out there, free and otherwise.

Comment: great stuff! Thanks!